# services setup project showing Error

Tags: service, setup-project

I create One Windows services to scheduling SQL backup,
Its runs perfectly when i install it by visual studio command prompt, installutil services.exe,

Now i need to make it setup so, i can give this services to my client also,
I found http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816169 this link very userful
i create setup file, and it also install services,
but when i start services by right click on service, 
it start perfectly in my PC but in other Pc its shows error
[image]

kindly help me to create setup file for services

Comment: Did you check if the service has the correct permissions ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you see that message when the service is started by the system but stops quickly without completing the protocol message/event exchange. Your service is starting and then just finishing, so you need to figure out what it's doing, even if it's just "On Exception go to end of program".